# How to do zooming and panning in image using xamarin cross platform

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to zoom and pan an image in my app.But it is not working perfectly.

I tried this link: [https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74168/full-screen-image-viewer-with-pinch-to-zoom-pan-to-move-tap-to-show-captions-for-xamarin-forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RYdm.png)

Please help me..

Here is my XAML Code

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        <Image Source="download" x:Name="img">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanUpdated"/>
                <PinchGestureRecognizer PinchUpdated="OnPinchUpdated"/>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped"/>
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

My mainpage.cs

```
    private const double MIN_SCALE = 1;
    private const double MAX_SCALE = 4;
    private const double OVERSHOOT = 0.15;
    private double StartScale;
    private double LastX, LastY;
    private double StartX, StartY;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
        return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
    }

    private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Scale > MIN_SCALE)
        {
            this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
            this.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
        else
        {
            AnchorX = AnchorY = 0.5; //TODO tapped position
            this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
    }

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Scale > MIN_SCALE)
            switch (e.StatusType)
            {
                case GestureStatus.Started:
                    StartX = (1 - AnchorX) * Width;
                    StartY = (1 - AnchorY) * Height;
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Running:
                    TranslationX = Clamp(LastX + e.TotalX * Scale, -Width / 2, Width / 2);
                    TranslationY = Clamp(LastY + e.TotalY * Scale, -Height / 2, Height / 2);
                    break;
            }

        //switch (e.StatusType)
        //{
        //    case GestureStatus.Started:
        //        StartX = (1 - AnchorX) * Width;
        //        StartY = (1 - AnchorY) * Height;
        //        break;
        //    case GestureStatus.Running:
        //        AnchorX = Clamp(1 - (StartX + e.TotalX) / Width, 0, 1);
        //        AnchorY = Clamp(1 - (StartY + e.TotalY) / Height, 0, 1);
        //        break;
        //}

}

    private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                StartScale = Scale;
                AnchorX = e.ScaleOrigin.X;
                AnchorY = e.ScaleOrigin.Y;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                double current = Scale + (e.Scale - 1) * StartScale;
                Scale = Clamp(current, MIN_SCALE * (1 - OVERSHOOT), MAX_SCALE * (1 + OVERSHOOT));
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                if (Scale > MAX_SCALE)
                    this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                else if (Scale < MIN_SCALE)
                    this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height); //must be called

        img.TranslateTo(0, 0, 0, Easing.Linear);
    }

    private T Clamp<T>(T value, T minimum, T maximum) where T : IComparable
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(minimum) < 0)
            return minimum;
        else if (value.CompareTo(maximum) > 0)
            return maximum;
        else
            return value;
    }

}
```

When I zoom the image ,the image position look like this

[image]
Image gestures is not working perfectly.When double tap the image ,zoom in and zoom out work perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean by *"After pan the image, the position of the image is altered."* it's a bit vague.

Comment: @Paul Kertscher when zooming the image, the position of the image changed